# can we extend Whitney’s theorem to multi graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Here is an introduction to  the Whitney’s theorem: 
https://www.math.hmc.edu/~kindred/cuc-only/math104/lectures/lect09-slides-handout.pdf
But it doesn't say whether we can use this theorem for multi graphs or it is just for simple graphs. So  is this inequality true for multi graphs ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "Whitney's inequality" is the same as "Whitney's theorem" but for more information on Whitney's theorem (about line graphs of graphs) see the paper "An analogue of the Whitney theorem for edge graphs of multigraphs, and edge multigraphs" at http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/dma.1997.7.issue-3/dma.1997.7.3.287/dma.1997.7.3.287.xml